# Intent with action and class

Tags: android

Can I initialize intent by giving it the destination class AND also setting action to it? I want to setup an alarm  and  I want the action to be the differentiating factor

Comment: Short answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("MyAction", null, context, ComponentClass.class);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String, android.net.Uri, android.content.Context, java.lang.Class)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))

Comment: I like that, very short and sweet